# Does stoi(char*) necessarily construct a temporary string?

Tags: c++, string, performance, stl

Does calling `stoi` with a (NULL-terminated) `char*` necessarily construct a temporary `string` and hence lead to a performance penalty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually yes it would. There is no overload of `std::stoi` that takes a `const char*` as an argument, so an anonymous temporary `std::string` is created.

That indeed is a string copy.

You could check the assembly code to see if that's what your compiler does. It might optimise to

```
std::strtol
```

or

```
std::strtoll
```

If your compiler doesn't make that optimisation, and it turns out (by profiling) that the string copy is a bottleneck, then hand-roll the alternative as above.

Answer (score 2):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), these are the following overloads for `stoi`:

```
int       stoi( const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos = 0, int base = 10 );
int       stoi( const std::wstring& str, std::size_t* pos = 0, int base = 10 );
```

So since there is no overload that takes a `const char *`, unless the compiler is doing some optimization, yes, if you enter a `const char *`, it will create a temporary `std::string` object. Of course, the compiler can do optimizations. If you look at [the assembly of this small program compiled with `-O3`](https://godbolt.org/z/nnbx6bhE6), you'll see a `call strtol` in `main` there. That means the compiler has indeed optimized the `stoi` out completely.